# Get spark conf values at Run time in the spark-scala shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have started a scala shell with the following properties

> spark-shell --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory
>   471859212

How do I get this info while I am in the shell?

Comment: this may work :  `spark.conf.getAll`

Comment: @chlebek   The variables in spark.conf.getAll doesn't include those. Also, they are nothing but the config params in Environment param in Spark UI